# How to change text after delay - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two divs with individual id's and a class to style the same.

foo_1 has a z-index so it's above foo_2.

```
<div id="foo_1" class="foo"><p>I'm awesome.</p></div>
<div id="foo_2" class="foo"><p>No, I am.</p></div>
```

What I'd like to do is to have foo_1 fade out with foo_2 behind it.

I did try this;

#### HTML

```
<div id="foo_1" class="foo"><p>I'm awesome</p></div>
<div id="foo_2" class="foo" style="display: none;"><p>No, I am.</p></div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        $("#foo_1").fadeOut("slow", function ()
        {
            $("#foo_1").remove();                
            $("#foo_1").html($("#foo_2").text());
            $("#foo_1").show();
        });
     }, 5000);
 });
```

​
Thanks!

Comment: How can you manipulate `#foo_1` element if you `remove` it first?

Comment: *What I'd like to do is to have foo_1 fade out with foo_2 behind it.* - can you please clarify what you mean there?

Comment: @VisioN I don't know personally, I saw it on an StackOverflow question.

Comment: @Niko What I mean is that both foo_1 & foo_2 are the same size just with different text centered on the page. foo_1 has a higher z-index than foo_2 so foo_1 is 'above' foo_2 (by above I mean you can't see foo_2). I then want foo_1 to fade out so it shows foo_2.

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function()
    {
        $("#foo_1").fadeOut("slow", function ()
        {
            // remove $("#foo_1").remove(); 
            // line from code, 
            // because, its removing #foo_1 from dom, 
            // so in next strp you can't catch it

            // $("#foo_1").remove();           
            $("#foo_1").html($("#foo_2").text());
            $("#foo_1").show();
        });
     }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like what you're doing is a bit of an overkill.

Let me summarize: You have two divs, they are positioned at the same spot, but only #foo_1 is visible because it's on top. You now want to hide #foo_1 to reveal #foo_2.

So it should be sufficient to make #foo_2 visible while fading out #foo_1:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // Make #foo_2 visible
    $('#foo_2').show();

    // Fade out #foo_1
    $('#foo_1').fadeOut('slow');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use standard jQuery function with parameter in ms `FadeOut(500)`, `FadeIn(500)`:

```js
$(document).ready( function ()
{
  $('#foo_1').fadeOut(1500);
  $('#foo_2').text('No, I am!').fadeIn(1000);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='foo_1' style='display:block;'> I'm awesome </div>
<div id ='foo_2' style='display:none;'></div>
```